# XML get data by element attr

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing

Hi i have some problem with xml parsing. So - i want to read data from some xml tags by data. Can you help me? This is my code.

```
    <data>
        <element name="name">Zook</element>
        <element name="image">img/icons/01/zook.png</element>
    </data>
```

and jquery

```
$(this).find("element").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    $("#div").html('<span>' + name + '</span>')
});
```

Comment: And what's happening currently?

Comment: in output i have name or image, no Zook or url

Comment: Have edited my answer, are you able to restructure your XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code will extract the data for you:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "path/to/your/xml.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml){
   $(xml).find("element").each(function() {
          var name = $(this).find("name").text();
          var image = $(this).find("image").text();
          $("#div").html('<span>' + name + '</span>');
   });
});
```

You will need to restructure your xml though, as at present element has a dual meaning. 
Simplify this so that your data looks like this:

```
<data>
  <element>
    <image>path/to/img.ext</image>
    <name>Name</name>
  </element>
</data>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just go through this
[Link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery)
it explains everything you need :)

```
$(xml).find("element").each(function()
 {
   $("#output").append($(this).attr("name") + "<br />");
 });
```

Comment: there is no info about tag name parsing, only by tag

Comment: the same, i have an tags names in output no data

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = $(this).text();
```

Should make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find("main_menu").each(function () {
    $(this).find("element").each(function(){
        var name = $(this).text();
        var image = $(this).text();

        $("#carousel_items").append('<span>' + name + '</span><span>' + image + '</span>')
    });
});
```

this is how my code looks like now

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find("main_menu").each(function () {
    var name, image;

    $(this).find("element").each(function() {
        // make sure they default to what they originally were if null
        // since one <element> has name other has image
        name = ($(this).attr('name')) ? $(this).text() : name;
        image = ($(this).attr('image')) ? $(this).text() : image;
    });

    // Build the items once you've looped through the elements within a <data> section
    $("#carousel_items").append('<span>' + name + '</span><span>' + image + '</span>')
});
```